# SQL - Distribution Count

Tags: sql

Hi I have the following table:

```
 crm_id  | customer_id

jon         12345
jon         12346
ben         12347
sam         12348
```

I would like to show the following:

```
Crm_ID count | Number of customer_ids
1                    2
2                    1
```

Basically I want to count the number crm_ids that have 1,2,3,4,5+ customer_ids.

Thanks

Comment: tag the DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, etc..) which r using.

Comment: Use `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to aggregate twice.  First, aggregate over `crm_id` and generate counts.  Then, aggregate over those counts themselves and generate a count of counts.

```
SELECT
    cnt AS crm_id_cnt,
    COUNT(*) AS num_customer_ids
FROM
(
    SELECT crm_id, COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY crm_id
) t
GROUP BY cnt;
```

Have a look at a demo below, given in MySQL as you did not specify a particular database (though my answer should run on most databases I think).

### Demo

Comment: The `count(distinct)` is probably not necessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're probably right, but that would assume that the data is completely normalized.  If not, there is no reason why the same customer could not appear twice.